# ¿cual es la falla en la conexión a la base de datos?

Tags: php

```
<table align="center">
<tr>
    <th align="center">Nombre</th>
        <td align="center">
        <select name="nombre">
        <optgroup label="Seleccione un Nombre">
        <option>
        <?php
if (!empty($_POST['nomb']) <> ''){
    $sql = "SELECT id, nombre, cargo FROM usuarios_bodega WHERE nombre like '%".$_POST['nomb']."'";
    $rs=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo  "<td align='center'><input type='text' name='id' size='10' value='".$row[0]."' readonly/></td>";
        echo  "<td align='center'><input type='text' name='nombre' size='15' value='".$row[1]."' readonly/></td>";          
        echo  "<td align='center'><input type='text' name='cargo' size='70' value='".$row[2]."' readonly/></td>";
    }
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

estoy tratando de conectarme a la base de datos y traer los campos de una tabla llamada `usuarios_bodega`, creo que lo estoy haciendo bien pero cuando hago la prueba no me está trayendo nada ¿que puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te esta arrojando?

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene $_POST['nomb']? ¿Qué valores están asignados en la base de datos que deberían tener coincidencia con la consulta?

Comment: El error es que no me esta mostrando los nombres que necesito traer de la base de datos.

Comment: Has probado a poner $row["id"], $row["nombre"],$row["cargo"] en el echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la linea `if (!empty($_POST['nomb']) <> ''){`

ya estas comprobando la variable `$_POST['nomb']`con la función [empty()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php), cual te dar un valor `Boolean`, es decir un: `True` o `False`.

También cambiaría la función `mysqli_fetch_row` por [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), la razón es por la facilidad de leer y/o entender tu código mejor.

Tu código actualizado:

```
if (!empty($_POST['nomb'])) {

    $sql = "SELECT id, nombre, cargo FROM usuarios_bodega WHERE nombre like '%".$_POST['nomb']."'";
    $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo  "<td align='center'><input type='text' name='id' size='10' value='".$row['id']."' readonly/></td>";
        echo  "<td align='center'><input type='text' name='nombre' size='15' value='".$row['nombre']."' readonly/></td>";
        echo  "<td align='center'><input type='text' name='cargo' size='70' value='".$row['cargo']."' readonly/></td>";
    }
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

**IMPORTANTE:**

Te recomiendo trabajar con [Sentencias preparadas - Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) o mejor aún con el moderno interfaz [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php), para evitar la vulnerabilidad a una [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Answer (score 1):

Para tu PDO te puede servir esto, en el archivo config.php pones tus datos.

```
<?php

class ConexionPDO{

    private $server;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $baseDatos;
    private $conexion;




function ConexionPDO()
{
        $argumentos=func_get_args();
        if(count($argumentos)!=0) {
            $this->server=$argumentos[0];
            $this->user=$argumentos[1];
            $this->password=$argumentos[2];
            $this->baseDatos=$argumentos[3];
        } else

        {

            include "incluir/config.php";
            $this->server=${$var1};
            $this->user=${$var2};
            $this->password=${$var3};
            $this->baseDatos=${$var4};


        }

}

public function realizarConexion(){
        try{
            $this->conexion=new PDO("mysql:host=$this->server;dbname=$this->baseDatos",$this->user,$this->password);
            $this->conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
             //echo "Conexion OK";
            return true;
        }

        catch(PDOException $e){

            echo "La conexion no se pudo realizar: ".$e->getMessage();

        }


}
```